# Are the finite groups inclusions, almost all relatively cyclic?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, permutation-groups, computational-group-theory

*Definition*: An inclusion of finite groups  $(A \subset B)$ is relatively cyclic if $\exists b \in B$ such that $\langle A,b \rangle = B$.

*Definition*: Two inclusions of finite groups are equivalent, $(A \subset B) \sim (C \subset D)$, if: $(A/A_B \subset B/A_B) \simeq (C/C_D \subset D/C_D)$ with $A_B$ the [normal core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgSAH.png) of $A$ in $B$.

*Remark*: The equivalence class of $(A \subset B)$ is completely characterized by the conjugacy class of a [transitive permutation group](http://www.gap-system.org/Datalib/trans.html) $G$ such that $(A \subset B) \sim (G_1 \subset G)$.

Let $p_n$ be the ratio of index $\le n$ relatively cyclic inclusions (up to equivalence).
 Let $\alpha_n = \liminf_{r>n} (p_r)$ and  $\alpha = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\alpha_n) $.

**Question**:  what's the value of $\alpha$ (or at least good bounds)?
*Bonus*: what's the asymptotic analysis of the sequence $(\alpha_n-\alpha)$?

*[GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) computation*:
Up to equivalence, there are $15341$ inclusions of finite groups $(A \subset B)$ of index $[B : A] \le 30$ and $\vert B \vert \le 10^4$, and among them, $12671$ are relatively cyclic (more than $80 \%$). Note that at index exactly $16$ (and without order restrictions) less than $70 \%$  are relatively cyclic.